# Batch file parsing

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, wmic

How do i get only the caption from the output of this batch command?

command

```
  wmic group where ( domain='%computername%' and SID='S-1-5-32-544') get caption
```

and the output is

```
Caption                         
abcdefgh768f\Administrators
```

I need to read only "abcdefgh768f\Administrators" from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "caption="
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
        'wmic Group where "Domain='%computerName%' and SID='S-1-5-32-544'" get Caption^,SID /format:csv ^| find "%computerName%" '
    ) do set "caption=%%a"

    echo [%caption%]
```

In the code, output of wmic has been required in csv format (fields are comma separated) and the sid field is included. That way, the caption field is the second field in the record (node field is the first) and sid is the last. This is done to avoid the inclusion in the caption field of aditional carriage returns that are added at the end of the line.

`for` command will execute the wmic command, splitting the line on the commas and taking the second field. `find` is included to avoid processing the headers in the wmic output.